# Delete sub folder if folder does not contain a file extension

Tags: batch-file

Updating this AGAIN!

This code is supposed to look for all sub folders containing *.cpr

If found - do nothing

If not - delete the sub folder and all contents within

The code seems to be running but the sub folders are not being deleted. It just seems like they were being scanned. Initially, it was identifying folders that do not contain the file then prompting me to hit Y to delete folders without the file. However, the deletion is not happening. I added the /F and /Q parameters to the del function on the last line.

What am I doing wrong?

Also, for testing I copied the folder and named it to "cubasedefault" but my main folder is called "Projects - Cubase Default"

How can I assign this folder with the spaces so the bat file understands that is the folder location and not separate commands? I tried quotes but that didn't work. Do I need to put something like % in the spaces??

Thank you

Thank you :)

```
echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f %%i in ('dir /a:d /b /s f:\cubasedefault') do (
  set _dir=%%i
  if exist !_dir!\*.cpr (
    rem do nothing
    ) else (
     del /F /Q !_dir!
    )
  )
endlocal
```

Answer (score 1):

```
FOR /f %%d in ('DIR /AD /B /O:N') DO if not exist %%d/*.cpr (rmdir /s /q "%%d")
```

This worked for me. It only looks at immediate subfolders and deletes them if they do not contain the file extension ".cpr"

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `rmdir`/`rd` to remove directories

`Del` just deletes the contents of the directory specified:

```
C:\Users\username>del pie
C:\Users\username\pie\*, Are you sure (Y/N)? y
```

Note the `\*` at the end which indicates it's deleting the contents (and only files, not subdirectories)

Whereas `rmdir`/`rd` deletes the actual directory (if empty):

```
C:\Users\username>rmdir pie

C:\Users\username>dir pie
 Volume in drive C is Win 10 System
 Volume Serial Number is 

 Directory of C:\Users\username

File Not Found
```

To delete a [folder and all subcontents](https://ss64.com/nt/rd.html) you can use the `/s` option, however **take care using this switch** as you may need to make sure you've scanned all subdirectories for `*.cpr` before doing this, or that you are at the end of the tree with no more subdirectories to scan!

(`rmdir` and `rd` are [identical](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/windows-xp-in/0596009003/re326.html) by the way and can be used interchangeably)